# How to modify grammar to remove left recursive error in ANTLR4?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, left-recursion

I'm trying to parse a language. The follow ANTLR4 parser rules are directly copied from the  language specification :

```
physical_value 
 : raw_value DIV factor MUL factor PLUS offset 
 ;

raw_value
 : (physical_value MINUS offset) DIV factor  
 ;
```

but antlr reports an error:The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive 
I don't know how to modify the grammar, Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_immediate_left_recursion

Comment: @DavidBrabant ANTLR 4 removes immediate left recursion automatically. This is indirect left recursion (also appears on the page you linked to, but in a different section).

Comment: could u please give me the exact document ? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot eliminate the left recursion from the rules you posted, because the only string it matches is an infinite sequence.

- `physical_value` *always* starts with a `raw_value`
- `raw_value` *always* starts with a `physical_value`

...and repeat

Comment: Thanks for your answer, u mean there is no way to modify the rules? I cannot do anything?

Comment: @sara: Could you post some sample input and what should be matched by the rules. Maybe there's a way to modify the rules.